# Display raw html in v-html attribute

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I discover problem with rendering html from vue code.
I need to generate span from vue with raw html inside

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:33%" v-html="diffText"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
this.diff.forEach((part) => {
    let color = part.added ? 'green' :
                    part.removed ? 'red' : 'grey';
    this.diffText += "<span style='color:" + color + "'>" + part.value + "</span>";
});
```

`part.value` is html raw.

Comment: Are you saying you _want_ raw HTML displayed in the output? or that you have raw html  visible that you wish to be rendered html?    If it's the first one, use `v-text` instead of `v-html`.  If it's the second one use the framework for what it's good at; instead of looping in javascript and stuffing the resulting html string into a single variable put  a `v-for` loop in the template and control the html from there.

Comment: @Daniel, since OP marked wrapping in `<xmp>` as accepted answer, they probably don't want the markup interpreted. Which means any future users might think it's an acceptable solution. Hence why I added a future-proof solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `<xmp>` tags.

```
<xmp>
    <div> I am a Div</div>
</xmp>
```

this will render `<div> I am a Div</div>`.

More ways to do this:

#### 1. Replace some special chars from your raw html string:

- Replace the `&` character with `&amp;`
- Replace the `<` character with `&lt;`
- Replace the `>` character with `&gt`

Comment: [`<xmp>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp) tags have been deprecated/obsolete since HTML 3.2. Which means that, even if they currently do work in some browsers, support for them can be dropped at any time. You should use `<pre>` instead. Official documentation: [HTML documents should not contain XMP nor LISTING elements](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html#SEC5.5.2.1).

Comment: replace special chars is best solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:33%">
      <pre v-for="(d, key) in diff"
           :key="key"
           :style="{ color: getColor(d) }"
           v-html="d.value" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
...
  methods: {
    getColor(d) {
      return d.added ? 'green' : d.removed ? 'red': 'grey' 
    }
  }
...
```

...will likely produce the result you're looking for. Since the contents of a `<pre>` tag does not get intepreted as HTML, you can also use `v-text` instead of `v-html` here.

*Note:* Unlike `<xmp>`, `<pre>` tags are not obsolete and their implementation across browsers is consistent.

Comment: this.diff.forEach((part) => {
    let color = part.added ? 'green' :
        part.removed ? 'red' : 'grey';
    this.diffText += "<span style='color:" + color + "'>" + part.value + "</span>";
});

Answer (score -1):

I find out that best solution is to replace all "<" to "<" and ">" to ">"